# Why do I get SIGABRT when trying to addObject to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I have two classes - BNRItem and BNRContainer. BNRContainer is a subclass of BNRItem. In order to cut down the amount of code I paste, assume the following that I have tested and know works:

```
+(BNRItem * ) randomItem; // allocate and init a random item.

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSMutableArray * subitems; // This is a property of BNRContainer class

main.m:

NSMutableArray * rand_items = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [rand_items addObject: [BNRItem randomItem]];
}

[rand_items addObject: @"HELLO"];

BNRContainer * rand_container_of_items = [BNRContainer randomItem];
rand_container_of_items.subitems = rand_items;

[rand_container_of_items.subitems addObject: @"THERE"]; // ERROR SIGABRT

NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------");
NSLog(@"%@", rand_container_of_items);

rand_container_of_items = nil;
```

If I `NSLog` without adding @"THERE", I see "HELLO" in my description so I know that I am able to call `addObject:` at that point. Why do I get SIGABRT when I am trying to access ivar "subitems" of rand_container_of_items? I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: plz, no more snake_case !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the **copy** modifier in your declaration.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSMutableArray *subitems;
```

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the NSCopying protocol conformance is inherited form NSArray, so my suspicion is that in this line

```
rand_container_of_items.subitems = rand_items;
```

`subitems` contains an immutable copy of the original array. Try removing **copy** from your declaration. If you need a copy use the `mutableCopy` method.

Comment: I'd suggest adding [rand_items mutableCopy]

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies here

```
property(nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSMutableArray * subitems;
```

You should not use `copy` here since it will return `immutable` copy of the object. So that you cannot add objects to it. It could be

```
property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * subitems;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is giving sigbart as when you allocate an array to mutable array, it becomes mutable.

So, when you are copying rand_items to rand_container_of_items.subitem, it is becoming mutable.

So, to make it immutable, try following :

```
BNRContainer * rand_container_of_items = [BNRContainer randomItem];
rand_container_of_items.subitems = [rand_items mutablecopy];

[rand_container_of_items.subitems addObject:@"THERE"]; // ERROR SIGABRT
```